# For XML file change prefix and suffix of InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve XML file support

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using `InternalResourceViewResolver` for resolving file names. Till now I was using only JSP so it was completely fine. Now for few requests I need to send xml files residing in my `WEB-INF` folder, but not getting idea how to exclude or include support these **XML** files

My controller is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sitemap/sitemap_index.xml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewXmlSitemapIndex(ModelMap model) {
    return "/other/sitemap_index";     //sitemap_index.xml is actual xml file residing in other folder inside WEB-INF
}
```

And in `dispatcherservlet` I have defined `InternalResourceViewResolver` like this:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should use a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver like this

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Here you can define multiple view resolver and you can choose the one to use for the XML

I hope this can help

Angelo

Comment: In this snippet how are you delegating a request to resolve to a xml file? I did not understood. And isn't `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` job is to delegate to other view resolvers according to the content? So that means controller is defining the content, but here how can I ask my controller to define a content type?